# What if i do pee in the temple?

Tags: karma

According to hindu scripures one has to suffer for their bad karma .
When i was a child i did pee in a temple by mistake , what will happen to me , will god punish me for this. What should i do ?
The temple was Mohan temple and i was 3 years old and my parents were carrying me in thier lap and as soon as they kept me down i did pee in the floor of the temple .
I think that it is a sin and god will punish me for this bad karma

Comment: no paap under 12 years of age.

Comment: @siddhantkumar . Welcome to HSE! Since you’re new, I’ll just explain a bit. The most authentic answers are those that cite references from scriptures. Rickross’ answer seems to meet the criteria and answers your question IMO. When the question asker (you) find the answer satisfactory, the answer is expected to be accepted by clicking the (✔️) on the answer, below the voting arrows. Also if you like the answer please consider contributing an upvote by pressing the up arrow on the answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

Scriptural position is that children can't accumulate sins. One becomes responsible for their Karmas once they receive initiation (or Upanayana in the quote given below).

Apasthambha Dharma Sutras say:

> 19 Children do not become impure until the first feeding with solid
> food has taken place;
>
> 20 according to some, until they have completed one year;
>
> 21 or until they are able to distinguish the cardinal points;
>
> **22 or until they have undergone initiation, which is the superior
> position**,
>
> 23 for it is through this that they come under the jurisdiction of
> the scriptures.
>
> 24 This last view is the authoritative one, 25 and it is the
> traditional teaching.*

And, in any case, children below five years can't be punished for their actions probably because they are yet to develop the understanding of what is right and what is not.

From Yama Smriti's Chapter 1:

> A father, brother, or any other relation should perform the penance
> for a child whose age is below the eleventh year and above the fifth.
> (15)
>
> **There is no offence or sin for a child younger than this. There is no punishment from the king for him, nor any penance.**

In your case, the act was done when you were three years old. So according to Yama you have not committed a sin and do not require to be punished.

Comment: Ani Mandavya rishi argued with Yama and increased age of offense to 14 at end of Dwapara Yug. That was reason for Yama's cursed to be born as Vidura.

Answer (score 0):

You were young and did it unknowingly. You will only be punished if you did out of disrespect purposely.

You won't be punished.

Comment: Welcome to HSE! Kindly visit the help centre on how to answer questions as well as [Guidelines for new users](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions)